# Which .NET SHA1 class is FIPS compliant?

Tags: .net, sha1, fips

I'm using the `SHA1Managed` class in my code, but this causes a problem when I run it on a particular machine. I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the
>   Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

The problem is caused by `SHA1Managed`, which is not FIPS compliant.

Which .NET SHA1 class is FIPS complient?

(I could just try them all out, I guess, but I don't have easy access to the problem machine, and I suspect I won't be able to enable FIPS on my development machine. And I'm lazy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [this blog post](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2007/10/fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms.html) helpful. [HMACSHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1.aspx) is FIPS compliant.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using SHA1CryptoServiceProvider from that list. HMACSHA1 is a bit weird in that its constructor takes a key, and its default constructor generates a random key, which was really confusing I can tell you when my hashes kept changing in value.

Comment: HMAC is a completely different topic.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [`SHA1Cng`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cng.aspx)?

Comment: Seems like this is not available in .NET Core or .NET Standard yet :(